# Implementing observer pattern over RMI

Tags: java, rmi, observer-pattern

I'm trying to put together an RMI chat server that features multiple rooms. However, being new to RMI, I'm unsure of how to implement the observer pattern properly, or if my premise actually makes any sense.

I have a `ChatServer` object, and a `ChatUser` (client) object. The `ChatServer` contains a list of `ChatRoom` objects.

Each `ChatRoom` extends `UnicastRemoteObject`. However, I wish to implement the observer pattern here, and have `ChatRoom` also extend `Observable`, which of course can't be done in Java.

The idea was to use the observer pattern to have all the clients receive updates when a `ChatRoom` receives a new message.

I was wondering if there's a way of actually implementing some sort of observer pattern in such a situation? I've had a preliminary check on Google, but most of the solutions I come across tend to be very convoluted or are a bit too over the top.

Otherwise, is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm doing things here (from the very brief idea I've given)?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: It's been a while since I've done RMI, but you don't need to extend `UnicastRemoteObject` if you instead export your objects manually. I'll try and produce a code sample from an older project, but look at the Oracle docs around exporting remote objects.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use RMI?

Comment: ChatRoom doesn't need to be Observable, per say, but could contain an Observer, which the Clients would actually register against. You may also consider searching for RMI call backs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply declare a `register(ChatClient)` method in your `ChatRoom` interface. The `ChatClient` will need to extend `Remote` and be exported as a remote object, just like your `ChatServer` and `ChatRoom` interfaces. The `ChatClient` would declare some callback method to receive message from the chat room.